# Error when selecting variables (with `varSelectInput`) and using ggplot with Shiny (Error: `arg` must a symbol)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to make a Shiny app which uses this function (made in R markdown):

```
ls_vs <- function(variable) {
dataset %>%
  filter({{variable}} != 254.948530) %>% 
  filter({{variable}} != 121.738080) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(y = life_satisfaction, x = {{variable}})) +
  geom_point(aes(color = region, shape = freedom_status), size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(color = "cyan") +
  labs(y = "Life Satisfaction", shape = "Freedom Status", color = "Continent")
}

ls_vs(economic_freedom)
```

I am getting the desired results with this function:

[image: Desired Plot]

Now Here's my attempt of integrating that into a shiny app:

The UI section:

```
tabPanel("Factor Comparision", 
               
               sidebarPanel(
                 varSelectInput(inputId = "variable", label = "Select Factor to Compare", data = dataset),
                 
                mainPanel(                                   
                  h1("Test"),           
                  plotOutput("ls_vs"),
                 )   
               )),
```

And here is the server section:

```
#Factor Comparisons
    output$ls_vs <- renderPlot({
      dataset%>%
        filter({{input$variable}} != 254.948530) %>% 
        filter({{input$variable}} != 121.738080) %>%
        ggplot(mapping = aes(y = life_satisfaction, x = {{input$variable}})) +
        geom_point(aes(color = region, shape = freedom_status), size = 2) +
        geom_smooth(color = "cyan") +
        labs(y = "Life Satisfaction", shape = "Freedom Status", color = "Continent")
    })
```

Upon trying to run the app, I'm getting the error:

[image: error]

Error: `arg` must a symbol

Have I done something incorrectly in the UI area or in the sever area? How does one correctly use `varSelectInput` in Shiny to make an interactive ggplot where one can change the variable to change the plot?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the code in markdown vs that in Shiny is Shiny passes string value of the variable (`"economic_freedom"`) whereas the function in markdown has been written to work with bare column names (`economic_freedom`).

Change the function to work with strings that can be done using `.data` instead of `{{}}`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

output$ls_vs <- renderPlot({
  dataset%>%
    filter(.data[[input$variable]] != 254.948530) %>% 
    filter(.data[[input$variable]] != 121.738080) %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(y = life_satisfaction, x = .data[[input$variable]])) +
    geom_point(aes(color = region, shape = freedom_status), size = 2) +
    geom_smooth(color = "cyan") +
    labs(y = "Life Satisfaction", shape = "Freedom Status", color = "Continent")
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked well. I have a quick follow up question, 
would you be able to offer some guidance on removing certain options from `varSelectInput`. My app shows the drop down menu with ALL variables, but I want to select only a specific set of variables to be shown in the drop down menu and hopefully rename them so they don't show up with underscores if possible. 
Thank you again.

Comment: You can pass subset of dataframe in `varSelectInput` i.e instead of passing `data` only pass `dataset[1:5]` if you want to include first 5 columns. You may also use `selectInput` instead of `varSelectInput`. In `selectInput` you can pass the values manually like c('A', 'B', 'C')` or subset of column names like `names(dataset)[1:5]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using "bang bang" operator with `dplyr::sym()` should also work.

```
#Factor Comparisons
output$ls_vs <- renderPlot({
  dataset%>%
    filter(!!sym(input$variable) != 254.948530) %>% 
    filter(!!sym(input$variable) != 121.738080) %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(y = life_satisfaction, x = !!sym(input$variable))) +
    geom_point(aes(color = region, shape = freedom_status), size = 2) +
    geom_smooth(color = "cyan") +
    labs(y = "Life Satisfaction", shape = "Freedom Status", color = "Continent")
})
```